# hide control if not more then 6 or lower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab. where data comes with dynamically. now i set a condition with jquery.
if we have more then 6 this controll will display normally. if we set equal 6 or bellow.
this control will hide. 
as this tab only show 6 and if i add more then 6 this control will appear in front. otherwise this will hide.

```
<div id="info-nav-container">
  <ul class="info-nav">
    <?php $counter=1 ; foreach ( $atts[ 'info_models'] as $tab ) : ?> //loop will be here
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info-nav-control ">
  <a class="info-nav-scroll" data-direction="up" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
  <a class="info-nav-scroll" data-direction="down" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a> </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery Which i tried to hide

```
if ($('.vehicle-nav li').find('li').length <= 6) {
  find('.vehicle-nav-control').hide();
}
```

Comment: Change `find` to `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is throwing errors in console.
`find('.vehicle-nav-control')` must be appended to jQuery object.
`=>` operator must be replaced with `>=` ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)).
JS code must be in dom ready function.
You never open `<li>` tag.
Selector `$('.vehicle-nav li').find('li')` will not find any items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lists = $('.vehicle-nav li');

    if (lists.length <= 6) {
       $('.vehicle-nav-control').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have found my issue. and now its work :)